# How to release lock on Postgres table after executing copy_from of psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, locks

I am building ETL pipeline with Python to load data from S3 to Postgres database. Since there are millions of records, I have to read data by athena in chunks and use an interator to load data into database. Pandas' `to_sql` is too slow, so I am using `copy_from` to copy data from buffer to the table. However after the copying, the table got locks. The number of locks are dependent on how many chunks of the reads are. The next step after this is to truncate that table. However since there are locks on the table, it can't be truncated. If there is only one chunk, the lock sometimes gets released after the load. Disconnecting from the DB does not seem to help with releasing the lock either.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DBNAME, user=USER, host=HOST, password=DB_PASS)
for data_df in list(data_iter):
    sio = StringIO()
    sio.write(data_df.to_csv(index=None, header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', sep='|'))
    sio.seek(0)
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as c:
            c.copy_from(sio, 'cost_settlements_stg', columns=data_df.columns, sep='|')
            conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        conn.close()
        raise e
conn.close()
```

Why isn't the lock released after the load? Do I have to explicitly find the pids of the locks and terminate them?

Comment: The only place I see you close the connection is during an exception. ```with conn.cursor() ...``` will only close the cursor on completion.  Since we don't see where the ```conn``` is created or what what else is being done on it, it is hard to say what could be causing the locking. Tailing the Postgres log during this might also help track down what is going on. Also showing the information from pg_locks would be helpful.

Comment: The lock should be released upon commit.  You are probably misinterpreting something, or the locks are coming form a part of the code you haven't shown us.  Please join pg_locks and pg_stat_activity and show us the query and status of processes holding the locks.